# Algolia-specific => How to access hit attributes within react jsx

Tags: reactjs, attributes, state, algolia

I have a clickable hit element in a page set up like so:

```
<div>
    <InstantSearch>
        <div>
            <SearchBox/>
            <InfiniteHits/>
        </div>
    </InstantSearch>
</div>
```

wherein `InfiniteHits` is a consortium of `Hit` objects:

```
//Hit.js
<a onClick={() => this.handleSubmit(props.hit.attrib1, props.hit.attrib2)}>
    <img src={props.hit.image} align="left" alt={props.hit.name} />
    <div className="hit-name">
        <Highlight className="ais-Highlight-header" attribute="attrib1" hit={props.hit} />
        <Highlight className="ais-Highlight-state" attribute="attrib2" hit={props.hit} />
    </div>
    <p/>
    <div className="hit-description">
        <Highlight attribute="attrib3" hit={props.hit} />
    </div>
</a>
```

and you can probably see what I was trying to do with `onClick` at this point,which is to save `attrib1` and `attrib2` into a state (but really anywhere) via `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit = (attrib1, attrib2) => {
    this.setState({
        attrib1: attrib1,
        attrib2: attrib2
    });
}
```

I'm pretty sure this hasn't been working because I `console.log()`'ed the inputs to `handleSubmit` and attrib1 and attrib2 were showing up as `undefined`.

**TLDR: My question is, how can I access attributes (which I have made sure via Algolia Indice Configuration are available client side) within my code so that I'm able to store what exactly was clicked on for use in the next page?**

For the curious, this is basically the full Hit file I'm working with:

```
class Hit extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            attrib1: null,
            attrib2: null
        };
    }

    render() {
        const props = this.props;
        return(
            <a id="cssID" href="/nextpage" onClick={() => this.handleSubmit(props.hit.attrib1, props.hit.attrib2)}>
                <img src={props.hit.image} align="left" alt={props.hit.name} />
                <div className="hit-name">
                    <Highlight className="ais-Highlight-header" attribute="attrib1" hit={props.hit} />
                    <Highlight className="ais-Highlight-state" attribute="attrib2" hit={props.hit} />
                </div>
                <p/>
                <div className="hit-description">
                    <Highlight attribute="attrib3" hit={props.hit} />
                </div>
            </a>
        )
    }
    handleSubmit = (attrib1, attrib2) => {
        this.setState({
            attrib1: attrib1,
            attrib2: attrib2
        });
        console.log(attrib1);//undefined :/
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the code link please?

Comment: @ctg https://github.com/joshua-yan/temp-for-SO the api key is redacted from `index.js`, let me know whatever you need

Comment: so in line 52 of index.js =>   <InfiniteHits hitComponent={Hit}/> and in line 27 of infinitehits.js you are trying to access by   const { hits } = this.props; Can you try const{hitComponent} = this.props

Comment: so the onclick handling should be being handled in ../components/Hits.js, because `InfiniteHits` is just a collection of `Hit` objects. @ctg

Comment: and by the way, `InfiniteHits.js` actually is never used or referenced, I ended up just using the builtin version of the object @ctg

Comment: anyway i added hitComponent and everything compiled fine, i switched to importing my local `InfiniteHits` object instead of the one from `react-instantsearch-dom` https://imgur.com/a/KGkqfNW @ctg i guess im just not seeing yet how this jives with `Hit.js` where I'm able to track the onclick and store the information somewhere

Comment: so the problem is fixed?

Comment: no, there was no compile problem to begin with, my problem if you read my original post is that I need a way to grab Hit attributes @ctg

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue?

Comment: no, ive been tied up with something else @SamuelVaillant

Comment: @SamuelVaillant I see you work for algolia, is there any chance you would be able to quickly find out what methods I am able to use on a hit prop to grab the affiliated attribute? this is the associated gist of where I am trying to get the attributes https://gist.github.com/joshua-yan/520fb481ba9875ba08590963a8924ff8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Hits`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hits/react/) & [`InfiniteHits`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/infinite-hits/react/) expose a [`hitComponent`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/infinite-hits/react/#widget-param-hitcomponent) prop that takes a component to render each of the record retrieved from Algolia. The `hitComponent` is rendered with a `hit` prop that contain the information stored inside your record. Here is an example of a record:

```
{
  "name": "MyName",
  "description": "MyDescription"
}
```

We can now create our component to render this record:

```
class Hit extends React.Component {
  onClickHanlder = (name, description) => {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(description);
  };

  render() {
    const { hit } = this.props;

    return (
      <article>
        <h1>{hit.name}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.onClickHanlder(hit.name, hit.description)}>
          Click on the Hit element
        </button>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

You can find this example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-instantsearch-infinitehits-with-button-nnivh).